# Rasa will not save slot from entity of intent

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu

new to the rasa framework. I've been trying to make a simple bot that would simply recognize the intent of me providing my name and then rasa responding with a phrase including my name. The problem is that it does seem to recognize the intent but if the name I give it is not included in one of the examples then the response just includes none instead of my name (meaning the slot is empty). I thought its because of the lack of examples but I added more than 20. It would only fill that slot if the name provided was one of the names provided in the examples.

Furthermore, I can't seem to use rules. I was under the assumption that on a technical level I can just use rules for one-off questions such as providing the name and the bot responding hello, *name*. I can only get responses if it was a story.

rules.yml:

```
# ask name confirmation
- rule: ask name confirmation
  steps:
  - intent: inform_name
  - action: utter_greet_with_name

# respond with name
- rule: respond with name
  steps:
  - action: utter_respond_with_name

# respond without name
- rule: respond without name
  condition:
  - slot_was_set:
      - name: null
  steps:
  - action: utter_respond_without_name
```

nlu.yml:

```
- intent: inform_name
  examples: |
    - I'm [Sarah](name).
    - Hi, my name is [Chris](name).
    - You can call me [Alex](name).
```

stories.yml:

```
stories:

- story: path 1
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: inform_name
  - action: utter_greet_with_name
  - intent: ask_name
  - action: utter_respond_with_name

- story: path 2
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: ask_name
  - action: utter_respond_without_name
```

part of domain.yml

```
entities:
  - name

# Define the 'name' slot with the 'from_text' mapping
slots:
  name:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: name
```

Thank you!

[image]
Using name mentioned in example.
[image]

Comment: What is the difference between `utter_greet_with_name` and `utter_respond_with_name`?

Comment: utter_greet_with_name is when I inform the bot with my name and it greets me back with my name. utter_respond is for when I ask it my name and it responds with name (or without if slot isn't set, at least that's what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, based on your entity category, you can benefit from different entity extractors. You can add Duckling, SpaCy, and CRF to your Rasa pipeline.  Here I suggest going with `SpacyEntityExtractor` as it has a pre-trained model good for recognizing Names, Companies, etc.

Here you need to first install Spacy lib.

```
python -m pip install -U rasa[spacy]
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

Then you can set up your pipeline in `config.yml` and add the following lines to deploy the entity extractor.

```
name: "SpacyNLP"
# language model to load
model: "en_core_web_lg"
```

and

```
- name: "SpacyEntityExtractor"
  dimensions: ["PERSON"]
```

For a better explanation of how to set up your config, pls refer to [Rasa docs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/model-configuration)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I'll be able to use Duckling since it doesn't work on Mac M1 chips. I think I've tried spacy as well. I'm beginning to think that entities in intents can only recognize names mentioned in the examples and if I wanted to provide anything unique then I'd have to use forms. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: You can use forms to force set slot values, but as long as your slot is filled by an entity you need to be sure that the entity is extracted first. I think spaCy can help you with recognizing the names that are out of your NLU examples. You can also give CRF a try to see if that level of customization helps. For this particular purpose, yu don't need Duckling as it's good for number and digit recognition.

Comment: Using spacy didn't work. Still only stores the name only if it was in one of the examples. The intent is being recognized and you would think that if the intent was recognized then so would the entity but nope.

Comment: You need to change your entity name `name` to `PERSON` to be detected by spaCy.